# Mosfets differing in aspect ratio

Tags: mosfet

Which are the mosfets exactly similar to the mosfet 2N7000 but differ in its  W/L ratio so that it can be used in applications where you need differing aspect ratios ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The manufacturers doesn't even state what "W/L" relationship the MOSFETs characteristics corresponds to. Why do you need this? If you want to replace it with a different part, you look at the datasheet and compare the relevant specifications.

Comment: And have a look at what you wrote in your title. Welcome to EE.SE!

Comment: What if I  need a current proportional to the ratio of aspect ratio's of 2 mosfets. Don't i need mosfets with different W/L ratios?

Answer (score 2):

You would typically only be concerned with the W/L ratio of your MOSFETs if you were designing an integrated circuit and laying down the transistors for those circuits.

Out here in the wide world of ready made discrete parts within packages, lead carriers and leads you will not be directly working with the MOSFETs in this same way. Instead the manufacturer of the part has characterized the MOSFET with a batch of parameters that you can study to see if the part is suitable to your design requirements. You will find these parameters in the part DATA SHEET. Some examples of these parameters include maximum drain voltage, maximum drain current, gate threshold voltage and gate capacitance. These parameters are what you select parts based upon comparisons

Answer (score 0):

If you take two 2N7000s and tie their gate, source, and drain terminals together you will have the equivalent of a single transistor with twice the W of a single 2N7000.

Other than that there is no reasonable way to obtain discrete MOSFETs that are identical except for different W/L ratios.

Answer (score 0):

the fets will not match:

--- made on different days, even years

--- process may have been tweaked for lower Ron

--- the fets are not side-by-side on the wafer,
      so the doping will differ

--- temperatures have no reason to be identical